# (nvim-dap) Clear breakpoints?

Tags: neovim

How can I clear all current breakpoints at ones in nvim-dap?

---

UPD: I wrote this little function to achieve that:

```
function! ClearBreakpoints() 
    exec "lua require'dap'.list_breakpoints()"
    for item in getqflist()
        exec "exe " . item.lnum . "|lua require'dap'.toggle_breakpoint()"
    endfor
endfunction
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this was [added](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/commit/739ace54617100bacc5b6890fccd1f46e7d6894b) literally the next day from when you asked.

`lua require'dap'.clear_breakpoints()`